# Query WikiData using Wikipedia categories

Tags: wikidata

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a WikiData SparkQL query that can retrieve all entities under a category?

For example: the wikipage of Barak Obama has a bunch of categories including: "African-American Christians", "African-American educators", "African-American feminists", "African-American lawyers"

I'm trying to find a way to select all "humans" what match those categories. The wikidata page of [Obama](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q76) doesnt have any of those categories so I'm not sure how to query this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q76 wdt:P910 ?category .
  ?link schema:about ?category; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name ?title .
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org";
                     wikibase:api "Generator";
                     mwapi:generator "categorymembers";
                     mwapi:gcmtitle ?title;
                     mwapi:gcmprop "ids|title|type";
                     mwapi:gcmlimit "max".
     ?member wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title.
     ?ns wikibase:apiOutput "@ns".
     ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
  }
}
```

adapted from [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Find_category_members)

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Your query gives me all sub categories, but I'm trying to filter down just the  instanceType of "human". I think I'm doing something wrong as the query is timing out. Can you pls help  me https://w.wiki/4d28   ?

Comment: Also, on line#2, shouldnt it be "wdt:P910 wd:Q76  ?category ." ?